# Laptop Internet connection monitoring

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring

I have a need to monitor laptops both Linux and Windows that are deployed to remote locations which we don't have physical access to all the time.

The laptops are used for different services but need Internet access, what we would like to have is a solution to alert us when a Internet has lost Internet connection

For web servers we use nagios and pingdom but wondering if someone has come across a solution that is lightweight and for laptops

Ideally having a dashboard to view what laptops are connected would be the best

Comment: From the top of my head, I would put chef or puppet in them and make it run every 15 mins,  if one doesn't connect to the central server then there s a Problem :)

Answer (score 5):

I've started abusing [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net) for this purpose (among others), configuring it as a system service on laptops, then locking down it's UI to prevent it from being able to be used by a local connection originator to manipulate or access files. I get connectivity monitoring and robust `rsync`-like backup of field data.

It's fantastic at punching through difficult network conditions, so once you peer a node with a central node (say, a backup landing pad itself backed up via more conventional means), you can use Syncthing's API on your landing pad node to track connectivity.

If you're looking for end-to-end IP connectivity, and not just "can the remote host reach the Internet at all" knowledge, you can disable NAT traversal and relay use, at which point there will need to be a clean, unfirewalled path between the two nodes.

The downside is that SyncThing is *very* much a rapidly-developed project, with the issues that carries with it.